# How to find the last time an asset was transferred from one wallet to another

Tags: wallet, nft, blockfrost, api

Sounds easy enough to do with something like Blockfrost but the best method I could find involved many API calls to different endpoints. It doesn't sound like something that should be too hard so maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding the question- but, are you not able to track the tx number, asset ID on Cardano scan?